# Swagger annotation for query parameters

Tags: php, symfony, openapi, nelmioapidocbundle

I am converting a POST request to a GET request. I am using NelmioApiDocBundle to document my API endpoints. I currently have the following (old) annotation:

```
/**
 * @SWG\Response(
 *     response=200,
 *     description="Success - return JSON",
 * )
 * @SWG\Tag(name="Open Vacancies")
 *
 * @SWG\Parameter(
 *     name="Message body",
 *     in="body",
 *     type="string",
 *     description="JSON string specifying a page number and page size",
 *     required=true,
 *     @SWG\Schema(
 *         type="object",
 *         @SWG\Property(property="page", type="integer"),
 *         @SWG\Property(property="pageSize", type="integer")
 *     )
 * )
 *
 * @Route("/open-vacancies", methods={"POST"}, defaults={"_format": "json"}, name="api.open_vacancies")
 */
```

Now I want developers to be able to call my endpoint with a url like `https://myapi.myapp.com/open-vacancies?page=1&pageSize=10`. But I don't know how to define the documentation in annotation form. Google hasn't helped me out much. Can someone point me toward the relevant documentation for this (or, failing that, type in an example of an annotation I could use)?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/ptbroy https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/NelmioApiDocBundle/index.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To document a query parameter, you can also use the `@SWG\Parameter` annotation, but you set the value of `in` to `query` instead of `body`

Example :

```
/**
 * @SWG\Parameter(
 *     name="pageSize",
 *     in="query",
 *     type="string",
 *     description="Description goes here"
 * )
 */
```